# How to set the SMS Protocol Identifier?

Tags: android, sms, pid, telephony

I am trying to make an SMS Client. However, I am not able to figure out if the TP-PID or Protocol Identifier can be set for a SMS before submitting it? Is there any way?

There is a `getProtocolIdentifier()` function but I cannot set the PID value.

Can someone please throw some light on this?

Comment: Hi WarrenPd, "there is a getProtocolIdentifier function" - where? what library are we talking about?

Comment: I am referring to android.telephony.SmsMessage library. There is a public method getProtocolIdentifier().  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html